# How to call StoredProcedureQuery several times

Tags: oracle, jpa, plsql

I need to call one PL/SQL procedure several times.

For example:

i have a some Oracle's stored procedure

```
procedure insData(a_ in varchar2, b_ in varchar2) is
begin
  --some actions here
  insert into tmp_table (a,b) values (a_, b_);
end;
```

and Java-code, that should call this procedure several times:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("insData");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("a_", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("b_", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
for (Entry entry : collection) {
query.setParameter("a_", entry.a);
query.setParameter("b_", entry.b);
query.execute();
}
```

But table 'tmp_table' contains only one record (first entry of collection). 
If i will move query's constructor into loop, it will work, but it is ugly. I assume, that there is sould be another way.

How to call this query several times without query recreation?

UPD:
The main idea is not to run procedure in loop, there is main idea to use created procedure several times with different parameters without recreating. I can do that with `em.createNativeQuery` (create a query once and use it several times with different params), but unable to do that with `em.createStoredProcedureQuery`

Comment: If you have to insert multiple rows at a time, why not create a collection table type in the database and then have that as a parameter. That way, you can build up your array in Java and pass it across to the database in one go?

Comment: Inserting a row it is just one of several actions, that i should to do by procedure. I leave it just to show, that "execute" called once.

Comment: No idea what is this "execute" method. You call getResultList() to get results, or getOutputParameterValue(). http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/stored_procedures.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Boniest you can use a collection and pass on the values in one go. See below:

```
create  type var_a is table of varchar2(30000) ;

create  type var_b is table of varchar2(30000) ;

create table tmp_table(a varchar2(1000),b varchar2(100))


create or replace procedure insData(a_ in var_a, b_ in var_b) is
begin

  FORALL i IN 1 ..  a_.count  
     INSERT INTO tmp_table(a,b)
     VALUES (a_(i),b_(i));

commit;

end;
```

Execution:

```
exec insData(var_a('A','B'),var_b('C','D'));
```

Comment: The main idea is not to run procedure in loop, there is main idea to use created procedure several times with different parameters without recreating. I can do that with em.createNativeQuery (create a query once and use it several times with different params), but unable to do that with em.createStoredProcedureQuery

Answer (score 0):

One query object can be executed only once. Ugly is calling query.execute() in a loop.